# search a large tab-delimeted file using another most efficiently

Tags: awk, sed, grep

I am trying to find a faster (most efficient) tool for searching a very large ~100GB `file2`. The input that is searched for is `file1`, which is just a list of `#'s` in a column (1 per line) --- there may be several hundred ---. `File2` is a sorted list of ids in a specific format, with the # from `file1` matching a `$2` value in `file2`. I have tried a variety of `grep`, `awk`, and `ack` commands and they all seem to work but maybe there is a better approach. The below command seems to help a bit but since there may be so many #'s to lookup maybe its not the best approach. Thank you :). Each of the below execute in ~40 minutes and `file1` only has 2 lines in it, it usually has 100. Thank you :).

```
<file2 sed -e 's/^/(^|,)/' -e 's/$/($|,)/' | grep -E -f - file1 > out
```

awk

```
BEGIN { FS=OFS="\t" }
NR==FNR {
c = ++num[$1]
beg[$1][c] = $1
val[$1][c] = $NF
next
 }
$2 in val {
for (c=1; c<=num[$1]; c++) {
if ( (beg[$1][c] = $2) ) {
    print $0, val[$1][c]
    break
  }
 }
}
```

**file1**

```
2307492
7349185
```

**file2**   `tab-delimited`

```
NC_000001.10:g.26131654G>A  7349185
NC_000001.11:g.25805163G>A  7349185
XM_006715659.1:c.1454-13758T>C  22
XM_006715660.1:c.1454-13758T>C  22    
XR_921761.2:n.662T>C    2307492
XR_922278.2:n.1307-31218A>G 2307492
```

**desired output**

```
NC_000001.10:g.26131654G>A  7349185
NC_000001.11:g.25805163G>A  7349185 
XR_921761.2:n.662T>C    2307492
XR_922278.2:n.1307-31218A>G 2307492
```

Comment: What is wrong with `grep -wFf file1 file2`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to make sure that the numbers in `file1` are specifically in the last column of `file2`, you can use `sed` with a generated command file:

First generate the command file with `sed` or `awk`:

```
$ awk '{printf "/\t%s$/p\n", $1}' file1
/   2307492$/p
/   7349185$/p
```

Then feed that to `sed` to process file 2:

```
$ sed -n -f <(awk '{printf "/\t%s$/p\n", $1}' file1) file2
NC_000001.10:g.26131654G>A  7349185
NC_000001.11:g.25805163G>A  7349185
XR_921761.2:n.662T>C    2307492
XR_922278.2:n.1307-31218A>G 2307492
```

If just the presence of one of the numbers in `file1` in a line of `file2` should be printed, you can use `grep`:

```
$ grep -wFf file1 file2
NC_000001.10:g.26131654G>A  7349185
NC_000001.11:g.25805163G>A  7349185
XR_921761.2:n.662T>C    2307492
XR_922278.2:n.1307-31218A>G 2307492
```

Or, with `awk` you might read the numbers in file 1, split on `\t` and test col 2 of file 2:

```
$ awk -F"\t" 'FNR==NR{fi[$1]; next}
              $2 in fi' file1 file2
NC_000001.10:g.26131654G>A  7349185
NC_000001.11:g.25805163G>A  7349185
XR_921761.2:n.662T>C    2307492
XR_922278.2:n.1307-31218A>G 2307492
```

Any of those (I think) will be as fast as you are going to get without a database.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if it will be faster than what you tried, but what I think of is :

Tranform `file1` in regex to pass to `awk` and while it parses each line of `file2` apply the regex :

```
awk -F"\t" -v regex=`awk '{printf "%s|",$0} END{printf "\b"}' file1` '$2~regex{print $0}' file2
```

Details :

`awk '{printf "%s|",$0} END{printf "\b"}'` will tranform :

```
2307492
7349185
```

To : `2307492|7349185`

As the previous regex is stored in the `regex` variable :

`'$2~regex{print $0}'` means : `'$2~/2307492|7349185/{print $0}'` ie : print the line if `$2` matched the regex

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
awk 'FNR==NR{a[$0];next}($NF in a)' file1 file2
```

So checking a condition here FNR==NR which will be TRUE when first file is getting read(file1 in this case). Then creating array named a whose index is $0(current line in file1 only), using next will stop cursor to go further, so that all further commands shouldn't be executed then.
Now mentioning condition checking if $NF(last field of file2) is present in array a if yes then print the current line of file2(awk works on condition then action method, so if a condition is TRUE then certain action should happen so in this case NO action is mentioned so by default will happen which is printing the current line of file2).